# Asp.net c# Button click call a procedure and Also opens in a target_blank

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to make a button that when clicked call a procedure but also opens in a pop-up. I can't find how to do it because all the search i did only tells me to put it on te clientclick :

```
<asp:Button ID="cmbGen" runat="server" Width="240px" Text="Générer le rapport"          OnClick="cmbGen_Click"></asp:Button>
```

the onclick opens up a pdf, and its not working well on Ie, so, to solve this i would like the pdf to opens in a pop up

not sure what i could do.. anyone got an idea ?

**EDIT**

The code is pretty big, but basicaly, depending on what checkboxed were checked, it will create a pdf file and show it. this works pretty well, but it opens up in the current page, i would like to make it in a pop-up

Comment: Any chance of seeing your C# code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't see you c# so it's not 100% sure what you want but why use a `asp:Button` at all:

```
<a href="myPDF.pdf" target="_blank">Générer le rapport</a>
```

Comment: The code is pretty big, but basicaly, depending on what checkboxed were checked, it will create a pdf file and show it. this works pretty well, but it opens up in the current page, i would like to make it in a pop-up

Comment: i could use a link, but im not sure what i would gain in using something else then a button.

Comment: @Charles-OlivierGosselin: You would gain the separation of the report-generating functionality from the page which links to it, allowing you to link to it from anywhere in other ways.  You may never need to, but separation of concerns is a good thing.  You'd also gain the ability to use the `target` attribute, since controlling what's a new window and what isn't is a client-side matter.

Comment: @Charles-OlivierGosselin see joe's answer above. You can't open a window from C#. You prob want to open a new screen and then execute the c# On_Load

Answer (score 4):

A `Button` always submits a postback to the server on the current window, so you can't directly tie a new window to it. You'll need to write some javascript to do that, and open a popup window.

You can do this lots of ways - you can hook up an event handler to the button so when it's clicked, it immediately opens a new window, and that window is pointed to your server code which returns the PDF. Or you can do a regular postback, and return some javascript that pops up a new window. But either way, javascript is the only way to get a popup from a form button.

Liam's suggestion of making a link instead of a button is probably the simplest method - you can throw an image on that link to make it look like a button if you want.

**EDIT**
Based on your comment on the other answer, your simplest bet would be to return some javascript on the button click method, using `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` or whatever Microsoft is recommending these days. You can do whatever logic you need to first, then get that into a new handler either through session or querystring parameters, and have the client pop up a new window pointing to that handler.

Comment: +1 Totally agree, was going to delete my answer but noticed you'd referenced it.

Comment: @Liam Thanks, i am going to try this